# bash shell - increment (associative) array value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Just want to share with you something I did not easily find by myself...

I am a newbie in shell script and was just wondering how can I increment a value of a an [associative array](http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/).

Let's assume this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A b # declare an associative array 

a="aaa"
b[$a]=1

echo ${b[@]} # display all the values
echo ${b[$a]} # display the first value (1)
echo ${b[aaa]} # display the first value as well (1)
```

---

The solution can be

```
((b[$a]++))
echo ${b[@]} # display 2
```

Now that I found it, it seems evident, but I spent some time to get it...

I hope this can save some time to people :)

Comment: Note, you should use quotes: `(('b[$a]'++))`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf What is the benefit of using quotes there?

Comment: @Bast, post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９There are a few glitches with the way Bash parses arithmetic: for example, try it with these keys: `a=' '`, `a=@`, `a=*`, `gniourf=hello; a='$gniourf'` or even better: `a='hi$(ls>&2)'` (and you're glad I only put a friendly command there). Surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As describe above, the solution can be

```
((b[$a]++)) #  or (('b[$a]'++)) for a more secure way as pointed by @gniourf_gniourf
echo ${b[@]} # display 2
```

Now that I found it, it seems evident, but I spent some time to get it...

I hope this can save some time to people :)